# How can i delete/update the previous console.write and write another on the same spot

Tags: c#

Pls i am doing a simple application like a calculator. The application listen to key press and update display based on the key pressed. The application display like a simple calculator with numbers all written form the console.write. How ever, it display the same whole output when ever a new console is written. I want to replace the existing text with the new one at the same spot in such a way that user may not realized the the effect . Please is there any way i can achieve this in console ?

I came across a similar question How can I update the current line in a C# Windows Console App?>Here . However, mine is quite long next with many lines writen below

```
        public static void writeTiles(int[][] tiles)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < iBoard.Count(); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < iBoard[i].Count(); j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(Indent(2) + iBoard[i][j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
         //   Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

please how do i achieve that ?

Comment: You need to clear the console or change where the console's cursor is. I imagine you are doing this as a learning exercise, and you may benefit more from learning other things that your exercise is designed to teach

Comment: Just read it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.console.setcursorposition(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @PTwr English please

Comment: @MickyDuncan whops, I forgot I have en-US set in cookie

Comment: Thank you for your time. I thin the link provide by PTWr is what i need . Thank you once more.